# Bootstrap how to make icon bigger

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Sorry guys just a simple question, got an icon, was wondering how to make it bigger in bootstrap.

html:

```
<div class="square1">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

looking to make the search bigger icon bigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `font-size` property.

```css
.square1:hover{
  font-size:2em;  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div class="square1">
<a href="#">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: 1 more quick question is well if i wanted to change the hover effect of the icon?

Comment: Updated post with hover effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the size of the icon by accessing it trough its class, or adding a class to it, and changing then the width and/or height property in CSS.

For ex. add mydimensions class to your icon class property:

HTML:

```
<span class="your-icon-class mydimensions"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.mydimensions{
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, samsaam! Your answer could be more helpful with some sample markup showing how you'd change the size or add a class. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you George, will do!

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  margin: 1em;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em;
  transition: transform .5s linear;
}

a:hover{
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="square1">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  </a><a href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  </a><a href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```